# How to disinfect nets and siphon tubing for tropical fish?

Tags: fish, medicines

I am losing fish every day, originally an ich infection, which appears to be treated. Now I am treating the survivors with Tetracyline because they are dying with red streaks on them. What is the best way to disinfect nets and siphon tubes safely and quickly that is cost-effective?

Answer (score 3):

Soak in bleach water. I use 1/10 bleach to water and I would let it soak for a good 10 minutes, but you can go longer. Rinse it with distilled water if possible, tap is ok, but RO or distilled is better, and let them dry completely. Have been doing it this way for almost 30 years and have never had a problem.

Just confirming you didn't try to treat the ich with tetracyline, correct? It's definitely not an effective treatment for it. Also because of the ich lifecycle, keep an eye on the fish because it's possible the ich disappears during the free swimming stage and it will re-appear on the fish later. Temp is by far the safest and most effective way to treat FW ich in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Put the items to clean in a saturated salt solution. It can be created by putting salt into boiling water until the salt no longer dissolves in the water and drop to the ground. It will kill parasite eggs which easily survive boiling. Leave the items in for 1 or 2 days at normal room temperature.

This might be a problem for the silicon tubes. Give it a try with a small piece of 1cm which you can cut of the end.

Answer (score 0):

the best is dipping it in hot boiling water for 2-3 minutes :)

Comment: That will not kill paracite eggs.

Comment: please mention one type of parasite egg that are able to survive boiling water i dont know of any life form big or small that can survive temperatures of 100c.